# Reduce vertical spacing/gap - for \listoftables, \listoftables between heading and first entry

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

The following MWE demonstrates the large gap between the heading 'List
of Tables' and the caption for the first entry in this list.
How can the vertical space between the heading and first line of text be reduced?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\begin{document}
        \listoftables   

        \begin{table}
                \begin{tabular}{ll}
                    1 & 2  \\ 
                    3 & 4  \\ 
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{This is my table 1.}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to the question [fncychap package - reduce vertical gap/space between header and chapter heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13357/fncychap-package-reduce-vertical-gap-space-between-header-and-chapter-heading/13358#13358) you could redefine `\@makeschapterhead`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
  \vspace*{-28\p@}% <- modify here for changing the space above
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \DOTIS{#1}
    \vskip -30\p@% <- modify here for changing the space below
  }}
\makeatother
```

I put comments next to the commands which produce the spacing. The original spacing below is 40 pt. You could use it with a different value, also negative values are possible.

Comment: this is not correct.  The line "\vspace*{10\p@}%" refers to the space ABOVE the heading.  Not below, between the heading and the text.  You can see the affect by changing 10 to -120, the page is shifted closer to the top, but the gap width remains.

Comment: @Ian: Didn't you see that I referred to the 8th line? This is commented out, like I said, the 40 pt. The line `\vspace*{10\p@}%` means the heading, but it doesn't matter here. Modify that as you like. I just left it the same like in the linked earlier question by you.

Comment: I worked out the issue.  You are correct!  The trick is not to comment out %\vskip 40\p@ but to set the value negative.  The values: "\vspace*{-28\p@}" and "\vskip -30\p@" worked best for me.  Thanks!!

Comment: This will change the space between the chapter heads and the following text for the whole document. This is normaly part of the typographic design of the document. If it is needed only for the `\listof..`'s then why not redefine `\listoftables` by adding negative space after the `\chapter*` command?

Comment: @Danie: I suggested a consistent change which applies to the whole document. Even though the question is about `\listoftables`, I assume that Ian doesn't want to have the spacing of the other starred chapter heads differently. Also, Ians earlier (linked) question was about headings in general. Note: the question and the solution concern starred headings only. @Ian: please clarify if you mean that or if unstarred resp. list headings are meant in general.